# How Can I read data from AD8361 RF Detector

Tags: raspbian, analog-to-digital, pi4j

I want to check if my microwave has a leakage. I figured out that I can use AD8361 module as an rf power meter. The question is how can I connect raspberry pi to ad8361 and how can I read the output voltage using raspberry pi.

Comment: you would need to use an analog to digital converter

Comment: Ah let me see. AD8361's RMS power output is analog 0~5V DC. You need an ADC (Analog to Digital Converter) to read that. What you need is a low resolution ADC such as 10bit SPI MCP3008. But if you have other sensors already using I2C, and no SPI bus handy, then you might consider I2C ADCs such as ADS1115. Ref: 
(1) AD8361 LF to 2.5GHz Power Detector Product Overview - Analog Devices
https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad8361.html#product-overview

(2) AD8361 LF to 2.5GHz Power Detector Data Sheet - AD
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8361.pdf. Cheers.

Comment: @Davithbul, you are welcome. Have a great and healthy day.  Cheers.