# DIY Rpi Triple Axis RF / EMF Detector using AD8362 / AD8361

Tags: raspbian, analog-to-digital

I have a 3 axis rf meter. This [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HQBE7L8). I wanted to see if I could make it with a rasp pi instead.

I found this [article](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109330/how-can-i-read-data-from-ad8361-rf-detector) using the AD8361 but it doesn't go up to 3.5ghz and its not 3 axis. Ideally I would like it to go higher.

The main features I need to build are;

-RF range: 38mV to 20V/M
-Frequency range: 50MHz to 3.5GHz.
-Sensors:Triple Axis (X,Y,Z)

The first two I believe I can get with AD8362, I have no idea how to get the 3 axis?

I believe I can just record the data and get the required features;

-Manual data memory (Max & AVG) records
-Calibration factor, Alarm and Clock settings

Can someone point me in the right direction? Is this even reasonable?

Comment: If you have looked at the Data Sheet for the AD8362, and compared that to the I/O available on the Raspberry Pi, you will know that you are contemplating driving square pegs into round holes :)  Instead of 3-axis, I would suggest the [following project](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/popular-electronics/build-field-strength-meter-9-1960-popular-electronics.htm) is better suited as a "first step" into rf detection and measurement. If you're determined, start by reading the [app notes on the AD8362](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad8362.html#product-documentation) & consider an Arduino.

Comment: Any thoughts on achieving 3 axis?

Comment: Not dead set on the chip, I think the AD8361 "plays" better. I was just stepping it up cuz I found the AD8362 as I was writing the question. AD8361 with ADS1115 or similar looks like it will work. I'm not opposed to Arduino. Just have the pi and I like getting my hands dirty.

Comment: You should go for it. AFAIK, the [Amateur Radio SE community](https://ham.stackexchange.com/) may come closest to a good fit for your question. If you wanna' do hands-on rf projects on RPi, there's lots of specialized hardware & software available, and [tons of project ideas to consider](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=raspberry+pi+radio+project&t=ffnt&ia=web). Don't miss the [GNU Software Radio project](https://www.gnuradio.org/) or [Hackaday](https://hackaday.com/). The possibilities are virtually unlimited.

Comment: Well, I think you can use 3 AD8362 (in X, Y, Z direction) and 3 ADCs, eg, MCP3008 (or ADS1015) x 3 for Rpi. Analog Devices is hacker friendly to give the PCB layout and BOM.

Comment: As far as 3-axis goes, you could [start here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMF_measurement) - I don't think this will answer all of your questions, but you may learn about some things (e.g. isotropic antennas) that suggest a direction to pursue further research.

Comment: Best of luck, and do let us know how this works out.

Comment: I'll upload the results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Question***

*How to DIY a Rpi based Triple Axis RF Detector using AD8362?*

---

***Answer***

[image: ad8362]

*(1) Using 3 AD8362s*

You can use 3 AD8362s (in X, Y, Z direction) and 3 ADCs, eg, MCP3008 (or ADS1015) x 3 for Rpi. Analog Devices is hacker friendly to give the PCB layout and BOM.

*(2) Using 1 AD8362*

You can use 2 little servos, TowerPro SG90 eg, to sequentially position to X, Y, Z axis and take reading.

---

***References***

(1) [AD8362 50 Hz to 3.8 GHz 65 dB TruPwr Detector Data Sheet - Analog Devices](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8362.pdf)

(2) [AD8361 LF to 2.5 GHz TruPwr Detector Data Sheet - Analog Devices](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8361.pdf)

(3) [How Can I read data from AD8361 RF Detector - Asked 2020mar15, Viewed 38 times](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109330/how-can-i-read-data-from-ad8361-rf-detector)

(4) [Amazon Latnex HF-B3G Triple Axis HF RF Power Meter Analyzer and Detector Measuring EMF Radiation-Cell Phones-Smart Meters-Cell Towers-WiFi-Microwave-Blouetooth-Calibrated-Used for EMF Home Inspections](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HQBE7L8)

(5) [AD8362 Documentation (Datasheet, Application Notes, Evaluation Board)](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad8362.html#product-overview)

(6) [AD8362 Eval Board Gerber File](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/evaluation-documentation/AD8362_a00380d_Gerber.zip)

(7) [ADP7102 20V, 300mA, Low Noise, CMOS LDO Data Sheet - Analog Devices](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP7102.pdf)

(8) [AliEXpress Panoramic Servo Mount Platform Anti-Vibration for SG90 - US$0.5](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32796305898.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.74b9877eua6Shp&algo_pvid=f9450c60-2e27-4315-82e2-eebc7a69145a&algo_expid=f9450c60-2e27-4315-82e2-eebc7a69145a-7&btsid=0be3743b15900393613483342eaf8e&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)

(9) [Mono-axial and tri-axial (isotropic) probe / EMF measurement - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMF_measurement)

(10) [AliExpress AD8362 Catalog](https://www.aliexpress.com/ad8362_reviews.html)

(11) [AliExpress AD8362 RF module RMS power detector - US$22](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32907540650.html?spm=a2g0w.search0306.3.118.4d2e2c92Lpb6XC&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=a5f5038b-63d0-4f08-9b6d-a22220997030&algo_expid=a5f5038b-63d0-4f08-9b6d-a22220997030-18)

(12) [AliExpress 10 pieces AD8362 - US$7.8/10 units](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32881541263.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0_10130_453_454_10618_536_317_537_319_10059_10696_10084_10083_10547_10546_10887_10307_321_10548_322_10065_10068_10103_10884_10545,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=d51ef576-1170-499c-b7bd-03ab9cb53d53&algo_expid=d51ef576-1170-499c-b7bd-03ab9cb53d53-1)

(13) [Best EMF Meters Reviewed - GeoEmf 2020](https://geoemf.com/best-emf-meters/)

(14) [EMF Protection Devices – Do They Work? - GeoEmf 2020](https://geoemf.com/emf-protection/)

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - AD8362 Summary*

[image: AD8362 Summary]

---

*Appendix B - AD8362 Evaluation Board Design Notes*

[image: AD8362 PCB]

---

*Appendix C - SG90 Servo Mount*

[AliEXpress Panoramic Servo Mount Platform Anti-Vibration for SG90 - US$0.5](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32796305898.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.74b9877eua6Shp&algo_pvid=f9450c60-2e27-4315-82e2-eebc7a69145a&algo_expid=f9450c60-2e27-4315-82e2-eebc7a69145a-7&btsid=0be3743b15900393613483342eaf8e&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)

---

[image: sg90 servo mount]

---

*Appendix D - AD8362 RF module RMS power detector product datasheet summary*

(11) [AliExpress AD8362 RF module RMS power detector - US$22](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32907540650.html?spm=a2g0w.search0306.3.118.4d2e2c92Lpb6XC&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=a5f5038b-63d0-4f08-9b6d-a22220997030&algo_expid=a5f5038b-63d0-4f08-9b6d-a22220997030-18)

---

[image: AD8363 Summary 1]

---

[image: AD8362 Summary 2]

---

*End of Answer*

Comment: you have always been right on the money!! Thank you so much!! I'm excited to try this out

Comment: Ha, so I am just a friendly poor hobbyist. Good luck and cheers.

Comment: Very bright you are. :) I actually think the 2 servo route might be better suited for me. Double Thx

Comment: I've ordered 2 samples of the AD8632 and I'm about to purchase the ADS1015. Is there anything else I should need. I also found this guy for the pano. https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/1967/1528-1106-ND/5154681

Comment: Your order looks OK. Good luck and cheers.