# Way to get signal strength from an RFID reader?

Tags: python, rfid

I am attempting to make a grid of RFID readers that can triangulate the position of a tag within their read range.

I am currently using MFRC522 readers connected to a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (4gb) and reading using the SimpleMFRC522 Python library.

This is great in that it lets me easily read from & write to the tags that the readers can detect.

I would like to try to triangulate the relative position of a tag by using several readers to gauge signal strength from each one, with the intention of scaling up to have a grid of readers (or antennae connected to multiplexers) that can track the position of a tag as it is moved across a larger area (think a few feet across).

Is this possible using MFRC522 readers, or is this something that could be done with other readers or a specific chip connected to other antennas? I can't see any methods to return signal data from the SimpleMFRC522 library, just read & write methods.

Is there a command I can send to the reader to return this data?

Comment: Perhaps you can consider two grids: RFID reader and RF detector. Or one RFID reader with a servo, another RF detector also driven by servo.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am open to suggestions on how best to accomplish an accurate and fast tracking grid. Although given i want to scale it up cost is a consideration, and rc522 is very cheap to buy hence why i started there.

Comment: You are welcome. I am just brainstorming. I only started learning RFID reader, RF detector, and GPS sensor about a year ago and have only played RFID and GPS for perhaps less than 100 hours each. I have not played with RF detector yet, because I think it is not that useful for my current project. For SimpleMFRC522, I am just scratching the surface. So I will be glad that all can join in to learn together. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

*Can Rpi4B 4GB, using SimpleMFRC522, triangluate a tag read by a grid of MFRC522 RFID readers?*

---

***Answer***

*Part A - RFID Reader Triangulation*

[image: rfid reader]

See Refs 1, 2

*/ to continue, ...*

---

*Part B - RF Detector Triangulation*

[image: RF Detector]

See Refs 3, 4

---

*Part C - GPS Satellites Multiangulation*

[ublox GPS-RTK2 Board (10mm accuracy) - SparkFun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15136)

---

And you can use a GPS board to do not only triangulation, but with 2,500+ satellites to ***multiangulate, to 10mm accuracy***.

---

[image: gps 1]

---

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***References***

(1) [RC522 - THM3060 RFID Reader ***Q&A***](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/517428/thm3060-rfid-reader-setup-issues)

(2) [RC522 - THM3060 RFID Reader ***Chat***](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112007/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-malcommand)

(3) [AD8632 - How Can I read data from AD8361 RF Detector - Rpi SE 2020mar15](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109330/how-can-i-read-data-from-ad8361-rf-detector)

(4) [AD8632 - DIY Rpi Triple Axis RF/EMF Detector using AD8362/AD8361 - Rpi SE 2020may21](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112643/diy-rpi-triple-axis-rf-emf-detector-using-ad8362-ad8361)

(5) [RFID Range Overview - What is the maximum read distance of RFID? - SkyRFID](https://skyrfid.com/RFID_Range.php)

(6) [Real-time Locating System - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_locating_system)

(7) [ublox GPS-RTK2 Board (10mm accuracy) - SparkFun $220](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15136)

(8) [Neo uBlox Neo-8M GNSS Module Tests - tlfong01, Rpi SE, 2020jul01](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113544/how-can-rpi-change-neo-6m-gps-update-rates)

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Appendices***

*/ to continue, ...*

---

*End of answer*