# Is joining NEO6MV2 module and RC 522 module together to Raspberry Pi possible?

Tags: gpio, hardware, sensor

I am new to this but from my initial project requirements, I will need to join  [GPS Module](https://www.jaycar.com.au/arduino-compatible-gps-receiver-module/p/XC3712) and [RFID Module](https://www.jaycar.com.au/arduino-compatible-rfid-read-and-write-module/p/XC4506) to a Raspberry Pi 4. Do the GPIO pins support the required output? Is there any guide on how to join two modules to Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Ah, nothing is impossible for Rpi. You might like to search "NEO^M", "NEO8M" and "RC522" this Rpi SE or EE SE forum for more details.

Comment: If you add "tlfong01" to your search, the newest results should be these:(1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116298/way-to-get-signal-strength-from-an-rfid-reader,
(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113544/how-can-rpi-change-neo-6m-gps-update-rates/113601?r=SearchResults&s=1|6.2778#113601. From these newest post, you can find tons of references to realize your innovative ideas. Have a nice project. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer **YES**.

The GPS module uses Serial = Yes you can do that with a Raspberry Pi

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md

The RFID module uses SPI = Yes you can do that with a Raspberry Pi

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/spi/README.md

And for the question about "How", there are a ton of tutorials on this topics that are easy to find.